# POST on Android HTTPS page returns empty page on answer

Tags: android, post, ssl, https, httpurlconnection

I am trying to do a POST request to a HTTPS url. Code below. The problem is that the

```
br.readline();
```

return nothing. No exceotions of any kind are trown.

I tried with other urls, some handcrafted in php to run on a local server and report back, I tried removing

```
br.flush();
br.close();
```

But I can't make it work.
I read and followed many examples here on stackoverflow and found on the internet, but really I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

The SSL part seems to be ok (no exception thrown as in other cases I encountered).

I tried with no SSL, same result. Nearly the same code used to work, I must have changed something for the worst. The test platform is a 4.2.2 Android tablet.

Permissions inside the manifest are as follows, some of them are needed for other purposes:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I tried this: [https post in android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284812/https-post-in-android-4-0) but no way. I read many other articles but I ran out of ideas.

The code:

```
package shub.wisprv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class example extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    public void example() {}

    protected String doInBackground(Void... stringarray)  {


        try {
            URL login = new URL("https://it.portal.vodafone-wifi.com/jcp/it?res=login&uamip=192.168.6.1&uamport=80&challenge=f5aa36b054101c5edd56afcd00a10774&mac=18-FE-34-58-B8-80&ip=192.168.6.2&nasid=90-35-6E-41-64-B0&userurl=http://www.amiga.com");

            HttpsURLConnection postConn = (HttpsURLConnection) login.openConnection();

            String postFields = "UserName=foobar@foobar.com&Password=password&chooseCountry=VF_IT/";

            byte[] postData = postFields.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int postDataLength = postData.length;

            postConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            postConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            postConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            postConn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            postConn.setDoOutput(true);
            postConn.setDoInput(true);
            //postConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            postConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
            postConn.setUseCaches(false);

            OutputStream wr = (OutputStream) postConn.getOutputStream();
            wr.write(postData);

            wr.flush();
            wr.close();



            String html = "";
            String inputLine;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConn.getInputStream()));
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                html += inputLine;
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";

    }
}
```

Which is called with:

```
new example().execute();
```

Comment: I suggest you take a short look into the http servers log files.

Comment: @arkascha Problem is that on my local webserver everything works, and I cannot access remote web server logs (it's a WISPr login process).

Comment: Hm, then you really have a problem. You will always run into the same issue again. Developing against a black box can get _really_ annoying. I would suggest that you get a "remote system" where you have access to...

Comment: Ok, I'll try to install a WISPr server and redo all tests against a local system as you suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to type this also

```
postConn.connect();
```

after setting all the parameters  You code will look like this:

```
public class example extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

public void example() {}

protected String doInBackground(Void... stringarray)  {


    try {
        URL login = new URL("https://it.portal.vodafone-wifi.com/jcp/it?res=login&uamip=192.168.6.1&uamport=80&challenge=f5aa36b054101c5edd56afcd00a10774&mac=18-FE-34-58-B8-80&ip=192.168.6.2&nasid=90-35-6E-41-64-B0&userurl=http://www.amiga.com");

        HttpsURLConnection postConn = (HttpsURLConnection) login.openConnection();

        String postFields = "UserName=foobar@foobar.com&Password=password&chooseCountry=VF_IT/";

        byte[] postData = postFields.getBytes("UTF-8");
        int postDataLength = postData.length;

        postConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        postConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        postConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        postConn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        postConn.setDoOutput(true);
        postConn.setDoInput(true);
        //postConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        postConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
        postConn.setUseCaches(false);
        postConn.connect(); //This is necessary to setup a connection 

        OutputStream wr = (OutputStream) postConn.getOutputStream();
        wr.write(postData);

        wr.flush();
        wr.close();



        String html = "";
        String inputLine;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postConn.getInputStream()));
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            html += inputLine;
        }

        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";

}
}
```

Comment: Adding `postConn.connect();` did not solve the problem. I'm still hammering. I forgot to say that this is part of a WISPr login process..